# Find All Anagrams in a String code not working

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, sliding-window

[Input link for which it is failing](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/516210076/testcase/)

For the given problem statement I come up with below solution but it is getting failed for one input in leetcode.

```
class Solution {    
  public List<Integer> findAnagrams(String s, String p) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int k = p.length();
    Map<Character, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();// hash map for string p
    Map<Character, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();//hash map for string s 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++) {
      Character c = p.charAt(i);
      if (m1.containsKey(c)) {
        m1.put(c, m1.get(c) + 1);
      } else {
        m1.put(c, 1);
      }
    }
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (j < s.length()) {
      Character c = s.charAt(j);
      if (m2.containsKey(c)) {
        m2.put(c, m2.get(c) + 1);
      } else {
        m2.put(c, 1);
      }

      if (j - i + 1 == k) {
        boolean isAnagram = true;
        for (int m = 0; m < p.length(); m++) {
          if (m1.get(p.charAt(m)) != m2.get(p.charAt(m))) {
            isAnagram = false;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (isAnagram) {
          list.add(i);
        }
        m2.put(s.charAt(i), m2.get(s.charAt(i)) - 1);
        i++;
        j++;
      } else if (j - i + 1 < k) {
        j++;
      }
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

I confirmed also the value in both the hashmap for occurrences of a is 10000 when i = 0  but still it is going inside the "if" block and setting "isAnagram" variable to "false". Can you please tell me why that is happening.

Comment: Integer != int. I'm not sure thats the problem, but you should work with equals! Since it's two Integers I'm quite sure no unboxing will be done...

Comment: work with both of these if(!m2.containsKey(c1) || m1.get(c1).intValue()!=m2.get(c1).intValue())    OR  if(!m2.containsKey(p.charAt(m)) || (int)m1.get(p.charAt(m))!=(int)m2.get(p.charAt(m)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to resolve it by using  this condition  if(!m2.containsKey(p.charAt(m)) || (int)m1.get(p.charAt(m))!=(int)m2.get(p.charAt(m)))

OR

if(!m2.containsKey(c1) || m1.get(c1).intValue()!=m2.get(c1).intValue())